# Failing ARM Template Deployment for Azure Load Balancer - Jenkins Giving No Error

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-load-balancer

I'm currently attempting to deploy an Azure Load Balancer instance to provide load balanced access to two firewalls. This is to provide a pseudo-HA configuration.

However, when I try to deploy this template using Jenkins, it gives me the following unhelpful response (even with the --debug command):

```
DEBUG: attempting to read file Test/deployment/azuredeploy.json as utf-8-sig
DEBUG: attempting to read file Test/parameters/deploymentParameters.json as utf-8-sig
DEBUG: No tty
available.
ERROR:
```

So it's saying there's an error but can't tell me what the error is.

I have two requests:

1. Can anybody tell me how I can find out what is causing this error? Any commands or tools I am unaware of?
2. If anybody is skilled with the Azure Load Balancer syntax for ARM then can you eyeball my deployment template and let me know if it has any immediate flaws. Code is below.

code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "vnet name"
            }
        },
        "subnet1Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 1 name"
            }
        },
        "subnet2Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet 2 name"
            }
        },
        "loadBalancerName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "name of the load balancer instance"
            }
        },
        "nicName1": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "name of NIC 1"
            }
        },
        "nicName2": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "name of NIC 2"
            }
        },
        "nicName3": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "name of NIC 3"
            }
        },
        "nicName4": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "name of NIC 4"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "virtualNetworkName": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
        "subnet1Name": "[parameters('subnet1Name')]",
        "subnet2Name": "[parameters('subnet2Name')]",
        "loadBalancerName": "[parameters('loadBalancerName')]",
        "nicName1": "[parameters('nicName1')]",
        "nicName2": "[parameters('nicName2')]",
        "nicName3": "[parameters('nicName3')]",
        "nicName4": "[parameters('nicName4')]",
        "subnetRef1": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnet1Name'))]",
        "subnetRef2": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnet2Name'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName1')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig-firewallBE",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef1')]"
                            },
                            "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')),'/backendAddressPools/firewallBE-subnet-pool')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName2')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig-firewallBE",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef1')]"
                            },
                            "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')),'/backendAddressPools/firewallBE-subnet-pool')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName3')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig-firewallFE",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef2')]"
                            },
                            "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')),'/backendAddressPools/firewallFE-subnet-pool')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName4')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig-firewallFE",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef2')]"
                            },
                            "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')),'/backendAddressPools/firewallFE-subnet-pool')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
            "name": "[variables('loadBalancerName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard"
            },
            "properties": {
                "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "firewallBE-FrontEnd",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef1')]"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "firewallFE-FrontEnd",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef2')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "backendAddressPools": [
                    {
                        "name": "firewallBE-subnet-pool"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "firewallFE-subnet-pool"
                    }
                ],
                "loadBalancingRules": [
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')), '/frontendIpConfigurations/firewallBE-FrontEnd')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')), '/backendAddressPools/firewallBE-subnet-pool')]"
                            },
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')), '/probes/firewall-lb-probe')]"
                            },
                            "protocol": "All",
                            "frontendPort": 0,
                            "backendPort": 0
                        },
                        "name": "firewallBE-subnet-rule"
                    },
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')), '/frontendIpConfigurations/firewallFE-FrontEnd')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')), '/backendAddressPools/firewallFE-subnet-pool')]"
                            },
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancerName')), '/probes/firewall-lb-probe')]"
                            },
                            "protocol": "All",
                            "frontendPort": 0,
                            "backendPort": 0
                        },
                        "name": "firewallFE-subnet-rule"
                    }
                ],
                "probes": [
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "port": 0,
                            "intervalInSeconds": 15,
                            "numberOfProbes": 2
                        },
                        "name": "firewall-lb-probe"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: how do you invoke it? does the same template work locally?

Comment: You mean running it directly from the CLI instead of via Jenkins? Unfortunately, my security administrator won't let me have the required access to run jobs in the CLI. Only our automation account has the required permissions, and I don't have access to that account.

Comment: ok, so you are using some sort of shortcut step? like built-in azure cli step or something along those lines?

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. It's actually an extra layer rather than a shortcut though - for additional security. I can't directly make changes myself, I have to create Jenkin's jobs with parameters that can be changed for later deployments. Jenkins then automates the job. The problem is that Jenkins isn't always capable of giving the CLI error message in full (or in this case - at all) so I can't always see what's wrong with my code. I'm going to consult directly with Microsoft as I've been unable to convince security to give me direct access to the CLI.

Comment: sorry, my question is: are you using batch\command line step, or some specific azure cli step?

Comment: Azure CLI step, running templates with the following code:

`
Write-Host "*** Deploying Load Balancer ***"
az group deployment create --resource-group rg-name --template-file "Test/deployment/azuredeploy.json" --parameters "Test/parameters/deploymentParameters.json" --debug
`

Comment: i dont use cli all that much, but generally with arm templates, they dont always return a real error. you would need to dig into the correlation id to find real error. you can use something like `az group deployment show` and get the output from it, and then get the correlation id from the error and get more data from [az monitor activity-log list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-activity-log-list)

Comment: Your suggestion to dig deeper into the CLI worked. Managed to convince my superiors to let me run it directly via the CLI and it was asking for a missing property. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case the error was due to a missing parameter that needed to be passed to the template